# How to subclass NSOperation class to make it concurrent in IOS?

Tags: ios, concurrency, nsoperation

I want to subclass NSOperation to make it concurrent, according to the Apple doc, I must override the following methods to implement a concurrent operation:

1. start
2. isExecuting
3. isFinished
4. isAsynchronous

But as per my test result, I can let the NSOperation object run in a second thread without implementing the "isExecuting","isFinished" and "isAsynchronous" methods.I just write the code.

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(main) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

in the start method and then in the main thread I execute

```
[myOperation start]
```

then the operation can execute in a second a second thread instead of main thread. Can someone explain this phe

Comment: Use `NSOperationQueue` to run your `NSOperation`. Setup the queue to be concurrent (or serial).

Comment: NSOperationQueue always executes operations concurrently, while taking dependencies into account.It cannot be serial mode

Comment: @Coinmigh it can be serial if you set the max concurrent to 1.

Comment: @rmaddy, yes, you are right. I understand the question I asked by reading the apple doc again, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a solution that today would be considered awful.

Either you need the advantages that NSOperation has to offer - you've just thrown all of that out of the window. Good luck. Or you *don't* need the advantages of NSOperation, then please learn about GCD and blocks and dispatch_async to make your life ten times easier.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @gnasher729. If you just want to launch an asynchronous method, don't bother to use NSOperation. GCD and blocks will be a lot more easier.

Back to why you have to implement `isExecuting`, `isFinished`, `isAsynchronous` besides `start`, it's because **NSOperation does extra work about state, priority, and dependency management**.

For example, you might want to cancel an asynchronous operation when you leave a view. The default implementation of `cancel` method in NSOperation depends on the state of operation. If the operation is not in a queue it will be finished immediately; If it's in a queue but has not been started yet, its `isCancelled` and `isReady` will be set to YES, and wait for the queue to call its `start` method. The `start` method will check the value of `isCancelled` property;  if YES, it'll be finished immediately.